# Copy Data - SharePoint Sites to Azure Blob using Logic Apps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

Able to copy all the folders, files and data from SharePoint Sites to Azure Blob storage using Logic Apps.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried? or what you have tried?

Comment: or any image of your workflow or logic app, to make it complaint

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: Hello Rithwik, i have attached the flow. I am new to Logic apps and doing some POC. In above flow i am extracting files from a folder. but i have to get data from Sharepoint sites

Comment: @HemantKumar Please edit your Qs with details to understand more about ask.

Comment: Hemant can you add images/screenshots of your workflow

Comment: @RithwikBojja Added the workflow. But the workflow which i created is reading files from Sharepoint folder. but instead of particular folder, i have to access sharepoint site and read all the data and move it to Blob.

Comment: You want to read from particular folder itself? or from all? Can you be clear!!! You want to send blob from all folders in all lists or particular folder in a list

Comment: yes from all folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`To get all lists and files use below connector:`**

[image]

Then:
[image]

Then:

[image]

**`If you want to copy files from a particular list:`**

[image]

Give list name like below:

[image]

[image]

**`If you want a particular folder files :`**

[image]

You need to give list name "/" slash and then folder name to get files of the particular folder.

Comment: RithwikBojja - Thanks for the help

Comment: How to handle the below situations:
1) if i have files in nested folders in sharepoint. for example Document -> test -> test1 -> and then in test1 folder i have multiple files.

2) how to get all the Site content, Site pages and attachments from sharepoint site to Blob?

Comment: @HemantKumar, Glad it solved your issue, try to open a new question, with clear flow and steps and your issue, community will help